# How to set delay between two js functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay

I have following js code:

```
clientData.reloadTable( "CreateCSV", "/create/file" );
$("#downloadFrame").attr("src","/download/download");
```

In above code. first statement is creating an csv file on disk. And 2nd statement is downloading it(Using iframe to download file because of error when using AJAX request ). It is downloading file but with previous content. It means that it prompts me to download file before it finish updating that file.

How can I force my 2<sup>nd</sup> statement to not execute before 1st statement finished its work??

Thanks

Comment: The ideal thing would be that the processing of one URL would 1) generate the report 2) write it to the HTTP response outputstream. In that way the response would wait until the report is ready. An alternative is checking when it's done periodically and download it only if it's ready.

Comment: What is the code for `reloadTable`? As far as I can see it's not any standard jQuery plugin.

Comment: clientData.reloadTable is calling a php function internally that creates CSV file on disk.

Comment: It's client side, can you post its code so we can help you add callback function like nEEbz suggested?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: Oh. Huge file using other js files as well.......

Comment: @Awan we need only the code for one function that is using AJAX.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to do something like this in Javascript is to use callback functions.

If it is possible to change the reloadTable function such that >

```
var callback = function () { $("#downloadFrame").attr("src", "/download/download") }

clientData.reloadTable("CreateCSV", "create/file", callback);
```

and then inside the reloadTable function, call the callback function once everything is done.

This is the true beauty of Javascript.

---

Otherwise you can also use setTimeout() if you have an idea how much time the reloadTable takes.

e.g. if it is to take 1 second. to complete, you can >

```
clientData.reloadTable( "CreateCSV", "create/file" );
var func = function () { $("#downloadFrame").attr("src","/download/download");}
setTimeout(func, 1000);
```

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't sound very robust. But anyway:

```
function start() {
  doFirstThing();
  setTimeout('doSecondThing();', 1000); // execute the secondthing in 1000 ms
}

function doSecondThing() {
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
clientData.reloadTable( "CreateCSV", "/create/file" );
```

if it's an ajax call. call your download function from it's callback.